# What's wrong with float("1,000")?

Tags: python

Very rusty with my Python. I have a list of Cost as strings. I'm trying to convert them to floats but when the cost is above $1000, the value is represented with a comma. float("1,000") returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
   decimal("1,000")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I know it's probably trivial but do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimal` is not `float`. decimal is a module. That is the reason for the error you get.

As for the commas, drop them first:

```
s = "1,000"
float(s.replace(",", "")) # = 1000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use re to remove any "," formatting before you convert to float.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(",", "", "1000,00,00")
'10000000'
>>>
```

Comment: `re` is overkill. `replace` is sufficient as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error that raise is because you are trying to call the module like this:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal("")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

you should rather do:

```
>>> import locale
>>> import decimal
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
>>> decimal.Decimal(locale.atoi("1,000"))
Decimal('1000')
```

so you can just do it like this

Comment: In the question the comma is used as a thousand separator. Your result is different.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri: ohhh thanks i didn't read the question very well :)